# java.util.Set is is failing ParameterizedType check

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following code. At runtime `typeClassz` is `java.util.Set`. But the typeClassz instanceof ParameterizedType evaluates to false. For `java.util.Set` it goes to else clause. Any ideas ?

```
final Type typeClassz = methods.get(index).getParameterTypes()[0];
if(typeClassz instanceof ParameterizedType){
    final ParameterizedType classType = (ParameterizedType) ((ParameterizedType) typeClassz).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    return mongoTemplate.findOne(query, (Class<?>) classType.getRawType());
}else{
    return mongoTemplate.findOne(query, (Class<?>) typeClassz);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Method.getParameterTypes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getParameterTypes--) returns `Class<?>[]`, so your `typeClassz` can only be a `Class<?>`, not a `ParameterizedType`.

You should use [`getGenericParameterTypes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericParameterTypes--) instead, which returns a `Type[]`.

Comment: Silly me. Whole time i was using generic method and somehow missed this completely. Thanks a lot :)